# Non-game mobile development with Unity

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, cross-platform

Recently, I've wondered if a non-game mobile app like Facebook could have been written all in Unity?

I am planning to develop a Social Media app and I am a .Net Backend Web Developer with no iOS/Android background. I especially know to code Objective-C and Java, however I don't have any experience or know-how about designing UI and add some animations to it.

I encountered the platform Unity while I was playing Dead Trigger 2 on my tablet. When I learnt that Unity is a Cross-Platform Game Development Environment, I tried playing Dead Trigger 2 on my phone (Note 3) and friend's iPhone. Works perfect. Then, I saw it has something to do with Facebook and shocked when realized that I am able to play the same game in a Web Browser on Facebook. That's amazing...

Since I am convinced that such a 3D game can be developed in such a way, I have the idea to develop a normal non-game mobile app with Unity. If the Dead Trigger Team can draw such zombies in 3D, I think it would not be so hard for me to draw a sliding-menu in 2D mode that magically works in all mobile platforms including Windows Phone. I did, and saw that any kind of animation is done with drag-drop editors and C# scripting, wooww. So, Unity fullfills my lack of UI coding in mobile platforms...

The question is, how about some backend stuff? Sending web requests? Multi-threading? async/await stuff we have in .Net? Periodically checking something from a server in background? Integrating the data with the UI?

Would you go for developing a Facebook like app all in Unity?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In short,unity is a game engine and as such it is designed for high performance. This means that even the lightest UI built can take up a lot of CPU and in turn - a [lot of battery](http://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/245841/using_unity_for_regular_mobile_app_development/), which is kind of precious on a mobile device. 
As stated [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/180243/threading-in-unity.html) unity doesn't seem to handle threads very well, though Im sure this is something that can be worked out
Anyway I believe that it is not the platform that answers your needs in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want C# on android, there is xamarin studio. I don't think that unity is ideal for such an application. You can use it, but if you don't need anything graphical, the overhead of the engine is not worth it. If you don't care about performance (think it more like power consumption, because it's not going to be slow or anything, just way more power hungry than a simple web browser), as the FB app obviously doesn't, then you could use unity.

What you are describing, already exists. It's called the web. It's as cross platform as it gets. And there are multiple ways to convert a web app (written in html5 technologies) to a "native" mobile app, both for iOS and android. I'd recommend that you followed this road, and not unity.

Comment: You mean like PhoneGap, I know. My lack is more about UI design than cross-platform. If I try to use Web to Native Technology, I am not able to code UI stuff in Javascript. However, power consumption issue made me stop and think... Thanks...

Comment: Unity has a nice UI system, but CSS and html formatting is much more powerful and 80% crossplatform (and this can become 100%)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can develop a non-game app on Unity. But, there are fallbacks, Unity will be a bit hard for developing the UI navigation part of the application. A social media like Facebook is more complex than just graphics. There is a lot of backend development. I don't think it will be too simple compared to coding it, but of course, you can do it. You should create non-game apps when you have to incorporate advanced graphics and/or physics.